# Checklistbox usando bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso criar um checklistbox, utilizando o bootstrap. Tentei de várias formas e não consegui. Procurei no site do bootstrap e os exemplos de lá, não cosegui também fazer aqui em meu projeto. Eu preciso de mais ou menos isso aí em baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [em suspenso] === não mostrar o código em `Tentei de várias formas e não consegui`

Comment: Fui postar a resposta e deu post fechado. Alguém poderia me dizer, pois não há sinalização de que foi fechado. Já descobri a resposta e queria partilhar com a comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seria isso:

[image]

Código do exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/giulianobg/uc8tghxe/

A seguir, basta adicionar os controles JS ou encapsular o código dentro de um `form`.